# Axon Framework AMQP - Doesn't fetches the messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, axon

I have developed `Spring Boot + Axon (Bootiful CQRS with Axon)` code by taking reference from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jp-rW-XOYzA&list=PLgGXSWYM2FpOa_FTla-x5Wd10dpmgrRC4&index=54

I've placed all by code here: https://github.com/JavaHelper/axon-tutorials/tree/master/axon-complaints-demo. The issue which I am facing is very weird issue.

**Scenario-1:**

If I start both the applications `(one on 8080 and other on 8081)` and hit the below end-points, then nothing is appearing in the RabbitMQ queue and thus, nothing is coming when I hit the `http://localhost:8081/` . It's blank.

**CURL commands**

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"company" : "apple", "description" : "My Kep"}' http://localhost:8080

curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"company" : "apple", "description" : "Laptop not working"}' http://localhost:8080

curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"company" : "Mastercrd", "description" : "Debit and Clearning does not works"}' http://localhost:8080
```

**Scenario-2:**

If I start the `demo-complaints` first and then hit above curl command then RabbitMQ shows the queues count 3. After that I start the `demo-complaints-stats` successfully, then nothing shows up on the hit of `http://localhost:8081/`

Could anyone please guide what's wrong ?

Source code link already provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo you're linking to is already relatively old. Or differently put, things might have changed which aren't clear from that start.
Have you check out the manual over [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/3.3/part-iii-infrastructure-components/event-processing#spring-amqp) and followed the necessary steps?

My hunch is that you haven't configured your AMQP Message Source to be the source of events for your Event Handler. To do that, you need to specify a Processing Group for your Event Handler and tie the AMQP Message Source to that Processing Group.

Comment: @ Steven - Thanks. Per Axon history, documentation is not very clear. Its confusing for newbie to understand Axon and its need when to implement it. Could you do favor .. Do you've POC's from minor to complex, so that can understood ? I only see Axon mainly use with CQRS

Comment: Could you please take a look at source code ? Link already shared above. Please try to reproduced it from your end. I am clueless what's going wrong all the time. I will be posting few more queries as I progress on Axon :)

Comment: @Sayali I'm sadly a bit hard pressed on time at the moment, so I wont check out your source code directly..
I can however tell you that over at AxonIQ, we are hard at work to make the journey into Axon a lot easier for you. The [Axon Quick Start](https://axoniq.io/download) might just be the thing to help you out for now. 
And we will be adding more tutorials, you can be sure of that.

Comment: Thanks for info. I dont want stop my analysis. But shortage of material on Axon will make me disinterested in using